# Template parameters inside and outside class/struct

Tags: c++

Are there any significant performance differences between the pieces of code below?

In the top piece of code, i create a struct and provide a templated function within the struct

In the bottom piece of code, i created a templated struct with the same function which is not templated

```
struct butterworth {
    template<class T>
    void fun1(T cool){cout << "fun1 called" << cool << endl;};
};


int main(){

    butterworth instance1;
    instance1.fun1<int>(9);

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
template<class T>
struct butterworth {
    void fun1(T cool){cout << "fun1 called" << cool << endl;};
};


int main(){

    butterworth<int> instance1;
    instance1.fun1(9);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would say that is more of a design decision than performance decision. In other words, does the entire struct depend on a templated type or just a specific function?

Comment: In the first case `instance1.fun1<int>(9);` can be written as `instance1.fun1(9);` so it saves on typing, but it really depends on the use case for which you should use.

Comment: Templates are a compile-time mechanism. That won't have any effect on run-time. But more importantly, you really shouldn't choose based on performance over (good) design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two classes model two rather different situations, hence it is not performance that should make you choose either of them.

I cannot find a better example, so bear with me...I'll use your code and simply rename things a bit.

The first case models entities of one type that can deal with various other types:

```
struct zoo {
     template <typename animal> 
     void add_animal(animal);
};
```

The same `zoo` can host various kinds of animals. Different instances of `zoo` are all of the same type, even if at runtime they deal with distinct types of animals.

The second case is different. It models entities of different types where each type can only deal with one specific other type.

```
template <typename animal> 
struct cage {
     void add_animal(animal);
};
```

Here, a `cage<elephant>` is a different type than `cage<fish>` (i warned you, its not the best example). They are completely unrelated types and have nothing in common (ducks aside, because duck typing bypasses the type system anyhow). You cannot put a `fish` in a cage for elephants or vice versa. Each `cage` instance has only a single method to add an animal that accepts only one type of animals.